# How to implement true function pipeline in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, pipeline

How to create a true function pipeline using C#? I got some idea like as follows, but it is not a true pipeline

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEachPipeline<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params Func<T, T>[] pipeline)
{
 foreach (var element in source) {
  yield return ExecutePipeline(element, pipeline);
 }
}

private static T ExecutePipeline<T>(T element, IEnumerable<Func<T, T>> jobs)
{
 var arg = element;
 T result = default(T);
 foreach (var job in jobs) {
  result = job.Invoke(arg);
  arg = result;
 }
 return result;
}
```

In the above code each element of `IEnumerable<T>` would able to get into the pipeline only after the previous element finishes executing all the functions (i.e. exits the pipeline), but according to the definition if `element1` finishes executing `func1` and start executing `func2`, by that time `element2` should start executing `func1` and so on thus maintaining continues flow of data in the pipeline.

Is this kind of scenario possible to implement in C#? If possible please give me some example code.

Comment: There is only a single execution context unless threads are introduced (the alternative approach with a single-thread is just the non-lazy result building at each step). With threads, each stage is just a FIFO queue passing messages around a "pump". Threads (actually, concurrency) also greatly increase complexity, perhaps see the .NET4 "Parallel" methods.

Comment: I have no problem in introducing threads, I need the work to be done anyway.. please share some ideas

Comment: Wouldn't PLINQ solve this already? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx

Comment: @bzlm Is PLINQ same as Pipeline? I have no idea, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From comment:* There is only a single execution context unless threads are introduced (the alternative approach with a single-thread is just the non-lazy result building at each step). With threads, each stage is just a FIFO queue passing messages around a "pump". Threads (actually, concurrency) also greatly increase complexity, perhaps see the .NET4 "Parallel" methods.

An "easy" method is just to configure N "starts" using [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) -- if and only if you can guarantee that the computations are side-effect free.

**Edit:** See comment(s).

Comment: That was an idea, but in this pattern how do I ensure that the result Enumerable is in the same order as the source Enumerable?

Comment: @AnindyaChatterjee: Rather than using `Parallel.ForEach` use Parallel Linq (PLINQ) via the `ParallelEnumerable` extension methods, which include the [`AsOrdered`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642142.aspx) operator to maintain your input ordering.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is more efficient than a true pipeline.  Pipelining only makes sense if operations can be run in parallel, but all these jobs are sharing a single CPU thread and so must execute sequentially even if pipelined.

If you understand that there won't be any performance improvement and still want to pipeline, leave a comment and I'll show how, but I first want to make sure you know what you're asking for.

Comment: Why do you think that true pipeline won't increase the throughput? Anyway I am very much interested to see a true pipeline implementation and I'll check myself the throughput of the two.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one main architectural element is missing, whether the job is handled or not. Pipeline is very similar to the traditional GoF chain of responsibility, take a look here if you don't have the GoF book around:

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx#_self1

I think you have to restrict your "T" to some interface that tells the pipeline if the job was handled (use the "where" statement).

Also, take a look into the PLINQ framework. I know it's not exactly what you're looking for (there, the intent IS to execute several jobs in parallel), but it might give you some good ideas.

Comment: If I apply this pattern it will be same as the code I mentioned above, it won't be a true pipeline anyway.